# Styling a datatable in a function and returning to layout

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have multiple dataframes that I want to display on my dash app.
They all undergo similar formatting so I want to do the dashtable formatting within a separate function to which I input the dataframe to be styled. I have tried below but I get "Error Loading layout" on my dash server

```
import dash
from dash import html, dash_table
import pandas as pd

def styletable(dataframe):
    # Create a copy of the original DataFrame to avoid modifying it directly
    styled_df = dataframe.copy()

    COLNAMES = styled_df.columns
    indexName = styled_df.reindex().columns[0]

    # Convert the styled DataFrame to a Dash DataTable
    styled_table = dash_table.DataTable(
        columns=[{'name': indexName, 'id': indexName}] + [{'name': col, 'id': col, 'type': 'numeric'} for col in COLNAMES],
        data=styled_df,
        style_data_conditional=[
            {
                'if': {'column_id': col, 'filter_query': f'{{col}} < 0'},
                'color': 'red'
            }
            for col in styled_df.columns
        ],
        style_header={'fontWeight': 'bold'}
    )
    print(styled_table)
    return styled_table


app = dash.Dash()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Mary Smith', 'Peter Jones'],
    'Age': [30, 25, 40, 35],
    'Salary': [50000, 40000, 60000, 55000]
})

styled_table = styletable(df)

app.layout = html.Div([styled_table])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Dataframe must be transformed into a dict with `to_dict('records')`

```py
def styletable(dataframe):
    # Create a copy of the original DataFrame to avoid modifying it directly
    styled_df = dataframe.copy()

    COLNAMES = styled_df.columns
    indexName = styled_df.reindex().columns[0]

    # Convert the styled DataFrame to a Dash DataTable
    styled_table = dash_table.DataTable(
        columns=[{'name': indexName, 'id': indexName}] + [{'name': col, 'id': col, 'type': 'numeric'} for col in COLNAMES],
        data=styled_df.to_dict('records'),
        style_data_conditional=[
            {
                'if': {'column_id': col, 'filter_query': f'{{col}} < 0'},
                'color': 'red'
            }
            for col in styled_df.columns
        ],
        style_header={'fontWeight': 'bold'}
    )
    print(styled_table)
    return styled_table
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `data=styled_df.to_dict("records")` instead of `data=styled_df`.

[image]